# Why supersampling is not widely used for image scaling?

Tags: image-processing, image-resizing

I look for an appropriate image scaling algorithm and wondered why supersampling is not as popular as bicubic, bilinear or even lanczos.

By *supersampling* I mean a method that divides the source image into equal rectangles, each rectangle corresponding to a pixel in the destination image. In my opinion, this is the most natural and accurate method. It takes into account all pixels of the source image, while bilinear might skip some pixels. As far as I can see, the quality is also very high, comparable with lanczos.

Why do popular image libraries (such as GraphicsMagic, GD or PIL) not implement this algorithm? I found realizations only in Intel IPP and AMD Framewave projects. I know at least one disadvantage: it can only be used for downscaling, but am I missing something else?

For comparison, this is a 4.26x scaled down image. From left to right: GraphicsMagic Sinc filter (910ms), Framewave Super method (350ms), GraphicsMagic Triangle filter (320ms):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Csvg8.png]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I know the answer. Because [pixel is not a little square](http://alvyray.com/Memos/CG/Microsoft/6_pixel.pdf). And that is why supersampling resizing gives *aliased* result. This can be seen on thin water jets on sample image. This is not fatal and supersampling can be used for scaling to 2x, 3x and so on to dramatically reduce picture size before resize to exact dimensions with another method. This technique is used in jpeglib to open images in smaller size.

Of course we still can think about pixels as squares and actually, GD library does. It's `imagecopyresampled` is true supersampling.

Answer (score 1):

You are a bit mistaken (when saying that linear rescaling misses pixels). Assuming You are rescaling the image by at most factor of 2, Bilinear interpolation takes into account all the pixels of the source image. If you smooth the image a bit and use bilinear interpolation this gives you high quality results. For most practical cases even bi-qubic interpolation is not needed.
Since bi-linear interpolation is extremely fast (can be easily executed in fixed point calculations) it is by far the best image rescaling algorithm when dealing with real time processing.

If you intend to shrink the image by more than factor of 2 than bilinear interpolation is mathematically wrong and with larger factors even bi-cubic starts to make mistakes. That is why in image processing software (like photoshop) we use better algorithms (yet much more CPU demanding).

The answer to your question is speed consideration.
Given the speed of your CPU/GPU, the image size and desired frame rate you can easily compute how many operations you can do for every pixel. For example - with 2GHZ CPU and 1[Gpix] image size, you can only make few calculations for each pixel every second. 
Given the amount of allowed calculations - you select the best algorithms. So the decision is usually not driven by image quality but rather by speed considerations.

Another issue about super sampling - Sometimes if you do it in frequency domain, it works much better. This is called frequency interpolation. But you will not want to calculate FFT just for rescaling an image.

Moreover - I don't know if you are familiar with back projection. This is a way to interpolate the image from destination to source instead of from source to destination. Using back projection you can enlarge the image by a factor of 10, use bilinear interpolation and still be mathematically correct.

Comment: "The answer to your question is speed consideration". But in my example supersampling it 2.5 times faster then sinc and gives better quality than triangle.

Comment: I am not familiar with your tests, your CPU and the size of the image. But bi-linear can be executed only few times slower than just copying an image. In other words this should probably take few milliseconds, rather than hundreds of milliseconds. On my laptop (Intel i7) resizing a 1.5[mpix] image to 0.24[mpix] (size of the image you posted) takes about 9[mSec]

Comment: This is a part of resized image. Here it the [original](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Louvre_Cour_Carree.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

Computational burden and increased memory demand is most likely the answer you are looking for. That's why adaptive supersampling was introduced which compromises between burden/memory demand and effectiveness. 
I guess supersampling is still too heavy even for today's hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: They are super-sampling.  I think the problem is terminology.

In your example, you are scaling down.  This means decimating, not interpolating.  Decimation will produce aliasing if no super-sampling is used.  I don't see aliasing in the images you posted.

A sinc filter involves super-sampling.  It is especially good for decimation because it specifically cuts off frequencies above those that can be seen in the final image.  Judging from the name, I suspect the triangle filter also is a form of super-sampling.  The second image you show is blurry, but I see no aliasing.  So my guess is that it also uses some form of super-sampling.

Personally, I have always been confused by Adobe Photoshop, which asks me if I want "bicubic" or "bilinear" when I am scaling.  But Bilinear, Bicubic, and Lanczos are interpolation methods, not decimation methods.

I can also tell you that modern video games also use super-sampling.  Mipmapping is a commonly-used shortcut to realtime decimation by pre-decimating individual images by powers of two.